# Has anyone ever seen this transmission line setup (double series terminated)?

Tags: pcb-design, transmission-line, series, digital-communications

I am designing a custom PCB interface to be used with some off-the-shelf devices. The relevant off-the-shelf interface they provide is cumbersome and doesn't fit my application, so I am designing my own.

I would like to control the impedance of the communication lines connecting my devices, but after some reverse engineering to try and find their termination scheme I find something I've never seen and can't find anywhere else: it's double series terminated. Don't even know what to call it really.

[image: the whole bus]

A1 and A2 are just signal buffers. A1 represents the source, R1 is part of the source. T1 represents the line I am trying to design. A2, R2, R4, C1 is one device's receiver. And A3, R3, R5, C2 is a different device's receiver. The application allows for multiple devices to connect to the same bus, essentially in parallel. Notice the two 50ohm resistors in series with the line. I don't know what to do with this.

Also as point of interest. One of the communication lines is different. In place of R1 there is a series inductor and series R=100. Everything else equal. My assumption is that is some sort of clock.

What do I control my TL's characteristic impedance to, if anything? Has anyone seen something like this before or have any suggestions?

Comment: What is the input impedance of A2 & A3? If it's high, then R2 and R3 aren't going to have much effect, and you just have an ordinary series terminated line.

Comment: If A2 & A3 have 50-ohm input impedance, then you have two 100 ohm loads in parallel, giving 50 ohms for the two loads; Now you have your line matched at both ends. This isn't the most power-efficient way to do things, but it may reduce ringing relative to just terminating the source end.

Comment: This is the driver they are using on both ends: http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/sn54ahc126.pdf  <br/>Not much info is available just the load capacitance.

Comment: @ThePhoton Well I just presented 2 devices in parallel, but they can be such that there are up to like 6 devices in parallel on the same bus. So I think that approach breaks down. At this point I'm inclined to think that the driver's input is high impedance. But why have R2 there at all?

Comment: You can guesstimate the input impedance of the HC126 from the \$I_I\$ spec, and it's well over 1 megohm. I don't think R2 and R3 are doing anything useful in this circuit in normal operation. They might be there to limit current in case the other cable end gets connected to a high voltage. They might be intended to damp ringing in the line with the idea of optimizing their values later (but I'd expect a 0 or 1 or 4.7 ohm resistor in that case).

Comment: @ThePhoton Thanks for the input. I am pretty convinced that this is just a case of a 50ohm series terminated transmission line. I was just so thrown by the extra resistor, but this seems reasonable.

Comment: Did they use a common mode choke with compensation ?

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 Not that I could tell. What's in the schematic I posted is all that is there.